# Export Mongodb collection using php

Tags: php, mongodb

I need to export `mongodb` collection using `php`, below is my code but it does not working,

```
$path =  "mongodb/bck.json";
$command = "mongodump --host localhost --username user --password pass --db order  --out " .$path;
$results = exec($command);
```

Whats the issue in the code? Any help appreciated..
Reference from here [Mongo Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: wats the problem above question I ask?

Comment: Did you read the link? You've not said what it does instead of what you expect. You shouldn't expect us to guess. Does the command run, but give an error or the wrong output? Or not run, and if so what's the error, etc.

Comment: yeah ok , for next I will change it....